# How to use pycharm venv at cross-platform (at linux - windows etc..)?

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment in pycharm on windows.

I've cloned the project to a linux machine running Ubuntu 18.04 and
tried creating a venv with same name at linux (I overwrote it with `virtualenv venv`) but I had to install requirements again.

Is there an any way run this *existing* venv to linux?

Comment: Virtual environments should be used on the system they have been created on. They are unique to the environment (OS, libraries, architecture, Python version, ...) especially if C code is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this simply because windows executables will not run on linux, just make sure you have a requirements.txt file. Additionally, you'll run into other problems where venv `bin` scripts have improper `#!` lines if copy the venv.